# I need to scrape data with python from webpage but by giving inputs

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape data from the website - [Link](https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/)
and store it in database or any one
but it requires some input parameters like i need to enter the vehicle number then submit it after submitting , I need to check again if it is my car.

After that i need to extract the red , yellow and green text .

Can anyone help me please it's important to me.[image: Image to extract]

[image: Need to extract]

I'm expecting the red, yellow and green data to scrape

Comment: This looks like a job for Selenium.

Comment: Do you want help or want the job done?

Comment: what have you done so far, and what issue/s are you having? If you're used to python, I think this is fairly simple to do with [selenium](https://medium.com/featurepreneur/an-introduction-to-web-automation-using-selenium-python-2ad84814b11c), but it you don't like coding, you can use something like [uipath](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/example-of-automatic-recording-with-web) where you can literally record an entire sequence of actions [ and also go back and [edit conditions into the workflow](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/the-if-activity) ] to automate these kinds of processes

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


num = "LE02WVX"

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        s.get("https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/").content, "html.parser"
    )

    authenticity_token = soup.select("form")[1].select_one(
        '[name="authenticity_token"]'
    )["value"]

    payload = {
        "utf8": "✓",
        "authenticity_token": authenticity_token,
        "wizard_vehicle_enquiry_capture_vrn[vrn]": num,
    }

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        s.post(
            "https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/?locale=en",
            data=payload,
        ).content,
        "html.parser",
    )

    authenticity_token = soup.select("form")[1].select_one(
        '[name="authenticity_token"]'
    )["value"]

    payload = {
        "utf8": "✓",
        "authenticity_token": authenticity_token,
        "wizard_vehicle_enquiry_capture_confirm_vehicle[confirmed]": "Yes",
    }

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        s.post(
            "https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle?locale=en",
            data=payload,
        ).content,
        "html.parser",
    )

    yellow = soup.select_one("main h1")
    red = yellow.find_next("h2")
    green = red.find_next("h2")

    print(yellow.get_text(strip=True))
    print(red.get_text(strip=True), red.find_next("div").get_text(strip=True))
    print(
        green.get_text(strip=True), green.find_next("div").get_text(strip=True)
    )
```

Prints:

```
LE02 WVX
✗Untaxed Tax due:1 July 2022
✓MOT Expires:3 April 2023
```

Comment: It giving me error                                                                                                                                  `File "c:\Users\Satyam Singh\Desktop\Web Scrape\project3.py", line 12, in <module>
    authenticity_token = soup.select("form")[1].select_one(
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Try using `soup.select("form")[0]`. If that isn't working, try to debug print the soup and look for where is the `<form>` located

Comment: I have done it using selenium and have installed correct web drivers but it gives error of "some device not working or USB device connected are not working something like that"   also I have written the code   sometime it works and scrape data and give the output but sometime it just open the chrome window and automatically get closed and doesn't scrape anything.  What's the problem? please someone help me

Comment: hey bro can you do this please?

Comment: Please someone help me i tried to print soup but it is giving me unwanted html code